# Node.js: Cannot access server from different device on the same network

Tags: node.js

NOTE: There are some others who have had similar problems, but those were solved by fixing small tidbits in the code involving how the server was listening (in examples that I've seen they put '127.0.0.1' as an argument in `http.createServer(...).listen()`. However, I do not have the same issue.

When I try to connect to my node.js server from a different machine on the same LAN network, Chrome says that it cannot connect.

This is testtesttest.js

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Working');
}).listen(3000);
```

When I try inputting `192.168.1.73:3000` (of course 192.168.1.73 is the ip of the machine that I'm running the server on) into the browser (Chrome, although I've tried other browsers as well and I have similar problems) of my other machine, it gives the error "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.1.73:3000". When I type the same address onto the local machine, it works fine.

I'm not exactly sure what to do. I honestly hope this is just a stupid mistake on my part (I'm sorry for possibly wasting your time) and not something that I have to go into my router for.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: What does this log? `.listen(3000, function() { console.log(this._connectionKey) })`. Also, it's not a firewall that's blocking incoming connections? Can you reach other ports on the same IP-number from other machines?

Comment: It logs `undefined`. Other ports don't seem to work either.

Comment: Are you running a Unix-type OS? If so, could you post the results of this (while your Node server is listening): `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`. That will give you a list of ports on which services are listening.

Comment: My household uses a telus router with the telus firmware. It has a firewall running on it with a security level that says 'NAT Only'. Would it do me good to try and completely disable it?

Comment: No that shouldn't be necessary since you're on the same LAN (*behind* the router).

Comment: Results of `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`:
http://pastebin.com/1gDktngn

Comment: Looks just fine, it's listening on `0.0.0.0:3000` so it *should* be reachable. I'm thinking there's something filtering incoming connections, check the network settings of Ubuntu if you need to enable incoming connections somehow.

Comment: mac guys: `sudo codesign --force --sign - /usr/local/bin/node`

Answer (score 37):

Try changing this

```
.listen(3000);
```

to this

```
.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works?

Comment: the listen function does not take the second argument as a string.

Answer (score 16):

Just putting this here in case it saves anyone else. I had this problem for two full days when trying to connect my phone to my local machine... and it was because the wifi on my phone was turned off.

Comment: Hahaha, this is priceless. Sorry you had to go through that.

Comment: Answesrs like these make me want to switch career after 20 years of coding.

Answer (score 15):

I too had this problem.
I solved it by allowing "node.js" in the network group.

Solution : **Allowing "node.js" through the private network windows firewall** 
a. Go to Control Panel
b. Go to Windows Firewall 
c. Click on the *Allow an app or feature through windows firewall* in the left sidebar 
[image: Click on the *Allow an app or feature through windows firewall* in the left sidebar]

d. Search for "Node.js : Server Side JavaScript" and make sure both public and private column box is marked tick for "NodeJS"
[image]
e. Click "OK" and you are done

Comment: if `Node.js` is not in the list , click `Allow another app...` to add it.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the step i followed which Worked

**My server code**

```
var http=require('http');
http.createServer(function(request,response){
response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
response.end('Im Node.js.!\n');
console.log('Handled request');
}).listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");;
console.log('Server running a http://localhost:8080/');
```

**Added inbound Rules.**

1. Created a udp inbound rule(since i could'nt find any http protocol).
2. Once created go to properties for the created rule.
3. Choose Protocols and Properties tab.
4. Choose any in Port Type. Click apply and Ok. Now i tried from other
   machine it worked!!!

I think you need to set Port Type to any to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It was running on 127.0.0.1 by me, that's why I could not access from another machine on the local network.

Answer (score 3):

You have to open 3000 port so that it can be accessed from remote machines. You can do that in iptables file. Use below command to open file

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

now add below line before the reject lines in that file

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

Now restart iptables service using below command

```
service iptables restart
```

Now you restart your server and try again. It should work..

Answer (score 2):

Chances are your firewall settings block incoming request on port 3000. You may want to add firewall inbound rule on this port to allow access to it.

Comment: Even if I add rules like http://i.imgur.com/ROScAoJ.png so, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the culprit was a VirtualBox Host-only Network interface. The presence of this network interface was causing `ipconfig` on the server to report 192.168.56.1 instead of the router assigned address of 192.168.1.x. I was accessing the wrong IP all along.

To remove the VirtualBox Host-only Network interface:

1. Open VirtualBox
2. Go to `File>Preference>Network>Host-only Networks`
3. Remove the offending adapter(s)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that, I have used IP assigned to my **ethernet adapter** instead of **wifi adapter**...

And it now works when I connect from any device.

Answer (score 1):

```
 http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Working');
 }).listen(3000, "192.168.1.36");
```

I found my IPv4 address on network settings, then specify with listen fun. put also 3000 port. I can reach http://192.168.1.36:3000/ via my tablet which is connected same wifi.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run that on the terminal:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Explanation [here](http://www.bonusbits.com/main/HowTo:Configure_iptables_to_Allow_Access_to_Common_Services_on_Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Like what Umamaheswaran answered, a new inbound rule needs to be created. But instead of using the UDP protocol, I have to use TCP. My application runs on a Windows Server 2012. The Inbound Rules are set in **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**, under **Administrative Tools**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using this algorithm. What it does is get all ip info from os.networkInterfaces, get all keys and loop trough it, filter by objects that contains family == "IPv4" and get it address value. After, it looks for '192.168.0.xxx' pattern and put it in possible_ip array. Any other ip will be pushed to other_ips array.

The export sentence is to turn it into a module js file.

import by `import {get_ip} from ./your_path/name_of_your_file.js`, or in common js `const { get_ip } = require("./your_path/name_of_your_file.js");`

Hop it helps

```
const os = require('os');
const _ = os.networkInterfaces();

// if common js use
// exports.get_ip = () => {

export const get_ip = () => {
    let ips = [];

    Object.keys(_).map(key => {
        let ipv4_obj = _[key].filter(obj => obj.family === "IPv4")
        let ipv4 = ipv4_obj[0].address
        ips.push(ipv4)
    })

    let other_ips = []
    let possible_ip = []
    ips.map(ip => {
        ip.includes("192.168.0.") ?
            possible_ip.push(ip) :
            other_ips.push(ip)
    })

    return { possible_ip, other_ips }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At night my mobile App was successfully accessing the local machine (a NodeJS server). In the morning it stopped working without any reason. After a lot of experimentation, including changing the port number and looking into the firewall, I rebooted my phone and it started working.