# AJAX POST request to node JS server not working from IPAD or IPHONE

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have an Apache server running with a website on Windows 10 OS. On button click on the website I make an AJAX POST request to an Express server in Node JS to run some code and return a JSON string. This works fine on my Windows 10 OS.

When I click the button on the website on my IPAD or IPHONE nothing happens. In the command prompt I see no console log of anything reaching the Express server.

Conditions:

- Firewall on Windows 10 OS configured to allow incoming data on port 80 and 443 (Apache) and 8000 (Express).
- On the IPAD and IPHONE cookies deleted and "Do not allow following" unchecked.
- All on the same LAN.

What am I missing here? (next, some code)
Express Server JS

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var cors = require("cors");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 8000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/FileName', function (req, res) {
    
    var Fname = req.body.fname;
    console.log("received filename: " + Fname);
    // Require the module
    var EasyFit = require('./dist/easy-fit.js').default;

    // Read a .FIT file
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile('C:/xampp/htdocs/ATP/FIT/' + Fname + '', function (err, content) {
    
        // Create a EasyFit instance (options argument is optional)
        var easyFit = new EasyFit({
        force: true,
        speedUnit: 'km/h',
        lengthUnit: 'km',
        temperatureUnit: 'celcius',
        elapsedRecordField: true,
        mode: 'list',
        });

        // Parse your file
        easyFit.parse(content, function (error, data) {

            // Handle result of parse method
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                //res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
                res.send(data);
                console.log('Parse ok');
            }
        });   
    });
})

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0');
console.log(`FIT app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
```

AJAX Request JS on client side

```js
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/FileName',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),                 
        success: function(result) {
            console.log('received fit in JSON');
            console.log(result);
            

    });
```

Comment: Replace localhost by the server's (your machine) IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out your ip address using a command like this:

```
ipconfig|findstr IPv4
```

Then substitute that for `localhost`

So you will have a line like

```
url: 'http://192.168.1.131:8000/FileName',
```

instead of the one that says `localhost:8000`

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've done that and still the same issue.

Comment: what happens when you just put http://[ip address]:8000/Filename into your browser address bar? Try it on the Windows machine and also the connected mac

Comment: Also tried that already. On my Windows machine I receive the response page from the Express server (so this works fine). On Safari on the IPAD and IPHONE I receive the message that the server does not respond.

Comment: This is a networking problem, not a javascript one. And it's very hard to debug remotely unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Chris. At least good to know that I've nailed the JS part! Could anyone give me any clues where to look for in my network configuration? Ports to open? Incoming or outgoing data? Firewall settings?

Answer (score 0):

After turning off my firewall it worked like a charme. Found the answer in the following post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48270227/10440418

Allowed the node.js app to go through my firewall. It works perfectly!